# Expanding black lines on edges of UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

As the title says, I have a problem where the edges of my `UITextField` have increasingly larger black space the more text that I put on. The cause might be the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    CGFloat textWidth = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[textField text], string] sizeWithFont:[textField font]].width;
    textWidth += 15;
    CGRect tFFrame = [textField frame];

    tFFrame.size.width = textWidth;
    textField.frame = tFFrame;

    return YES;
}
```

I have no idea why this is happening, and will put screenshots in case I'm not explaining it quite well.

Before the black lines

[image: No black lines]

Black lines started

[image: Black Lines Started]

Black lines keep filling up space the longer the text gets

[image: Black lines growing]

Please help!

Comment: Unrelated to the direct issue but your calculation of `textWidth` is invalid. It won't work if the user pastes text into the text field or deletes text. And changing the text field's frame in the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` method is a bad idea.

Comment: @rmaddy I do it because It seems like the only way to get a textfield to expand horizontally while typing. I might tweak it a bit though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the answer. A simple `setNeedsDisplay` after I set the frame of the textField. This prevents those growing black lines from showing.

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the border on that text field? It looks like you might be using a background image. If so, the image will stretch and distort as the text grows which could could cause a problem.

check: [resizableImageWithCapInsets:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:) in the apple docs for info on how to avoid that.

Comment: I actually allocate the UITextField programmatically and I set the border and background color: `textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine; textField.layer.cornerRadius=5.0f;
            textField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
            textField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor lightGrayColor]CGColor];
            textField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;`